# Casper JS returns only first row of a table

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a table as below:

```
<table id="securedTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="secured">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Lien Number</th>
            <th>Lien Type</th>
            <th>Filed</th>
            <th>Terminate Date</th>
            <th>Lapse Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="oddRow">
            <td class="borderedTd"><a href="javascript:generateFileNumberSearchResult(92919403)">XXXXXXXX</a></td>
            <td class="borderedTd">PO BOX 2576</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="evenRow">
            <td class="borderedTd"><a href="javascript:generateFileNumberSearchResult(92919732)">YYYYYYYYYY</a></td>
            <td class="borderedTd">PO BOX 2576</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the href of every link inside the first td of every tr of the table.
My casperJS code is as below:

```
casper.waitForSelector('input[id="nonStandardSearchFormID_0"], input[value="Search"]', function () {
        this.click('input[id="nonStandardSearchFormID_0"], input[value="Search"]');
        logMsg('Form submitted.');
    });
    casper.waitForSelector('form[name="resultsDisplayFormID"]', function () {
        if (this.exists('form[name="resultsDisplayFormID"]')) {
            logMsg("Data loaded.");
        } else {
            logMsg('No data loaded.');
        }
    });
    casper.then(function () {
        var rows = this.evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelectorAll('#securedTable tbody tr td:first-child');
        });
        var length = rows.length;
        logMsg("table length: " + length);
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            logMsg(JSON.stringify(rows[i].children[0].href));
        }
    });
    casper.run();
```

The code works and I see that the total number or rows is 54 which is correct however, it seems like only the first table row href is extracted because the error I get is this:

```
table length: 54
"javascript:generateFileNumberSearchResult(92919403)"
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'rows[i].children')
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: You're running as soon as the cells are added to the table. But the anchors may not have been added to the cells yet, so `rows[i].children` is null.

Comment: ohh ok so how can I solve this please? Also if it is the case, why does it give the correct number of rows 54 if some are yet to be created?

Comment: If there's an element that the application adds after it fills in all the rows, you could wait for that.

Comment: Also I though this casper.waitForSelector('form[name="resultsDisplayFormID"]', function is making sure the form is loaded that has the table inside it as it waits for it. Am I wrong?

Comment: The table exists, but the anchors haven't been added. I assume they're added asynchronously.

Comment: BTW, you could use the selector `#securedTable tbody tr td:first-child a:first-child` to loop through the anchors directly, instead of using `.childen[0]`

Comment: I checked by targeting the second td and getting its text instead of first td child anchor but I get the same result, first row data printed "PO BOX 2576" and the second shows TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'rows[i].textContent')

Comment: I do not think it is due to a time wait "table exists, but the anchors haven't been added" I did capture in a text file the variable rows using fs.write('rows.txt', JSON.stringify(rows), 'w'); before the for loop and the file text I get has all the data in it. See here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GFqOU4YRuK1_Wl5B892UaAZgBZ-ZhOB8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't stringify DOM elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238721/discussion-between-dev-dev-and-barmar).